# How to start a maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies, osgi, bundle

i have a simple plug-in project, which depenends on an osgi-bundle (for example org.eclipse.equinox.cm). This bundle has an Activator and is selected in the Run-Config (in OSGI "run"-case). My purpose is to use maven with tycho-surefire-plugin. I added in pom.xml the following:

```xml
<!-- Project stuff -->
<!-- Plugin stuff -->

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
    <artifactId>cm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-v20070116</version>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>

<bundleStartLevel>
  <bundle>
    <id>org.eclipse.equinox.cm</id>
    <level>1</level>
    <autoStart>true</autoStart>
  </bundle>
</bundleStartLevel>

</plugin>
```

After install, the bundle doesn't start and Activator wasn't executed. Does anyone have an idea? I use eclipse and several maven plugins.

PS: what is the equivalent osgi command `ss` in maven, so i can see the bundles?
Thanx

Comment: I think you're mixing up build tools with the runtime environment. Maven is a build tool, so it obviously doesn't have anything like the `ss` command, which lists bundles in the runtime.

Comment: Ok, but how can i start the bundle?

Comment: It depends. Are you even running OSGi yet? Do you have access to the OSGi console? How do you *want* to start the bundle... programmatically/automatically? Or manually? Much more context needed.

Comment: i run mvn install and i have no access to the osgi console. For the osgi console i need equinox.console as a maven dependency, however i cant start osgi console with maven, i only see the maven build output.   Finally i want to know how to start the bundle automatically and manually. It is like to convert the maven dependency into osgi bundle, then start it with maven.

Comment: Right. Maven is a **build** tool. Why do you expect Maven to **run** your application??

Comment: Generic rant coming up: some people are just **way too obsessed with Maven**! There's more to Java development than compiling and building! Sorry, this rant is not directed specifically at you... it's just a general annoyance which has been building for a while now.

Comment: Then i dont understand why the Activator of a plug-in project is started when mvn install? For example i have my-project with activator and i define something like this: <module>my-project</module> und <bundle>my-project</bundle> autostart: true. Activator starts. Why then i cant start the activator of an dependency?

Comment: It isn't. `mvn install` simply instructs Maven to build the project and install under $HOME/.m2/repository

Comment: after mvn install i debug and get a reference on an object, which was registered at the registry in Activator. It means Activator was started. I know that maven builds a jar file of this plug-in project in build directory. How then executes the activator?

Comment: You debug? You mean, you launch an application in debug mode in your IDE. This has nothing to do with maven! So, you need to give more context about how you launch the debugger, what IDE you are using etc.

Comment: <plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tycho-version}</version>
     <configuration>
        <argLine>-ea -Dosgi.clean=true -Ddebug=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true</argLine>
 <argLine>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y</argLine>

Comment: and then activate a remote debugger

Comment: this is defined in my pom.xml

Comment: And this is launched when you type `mvn install`?? So somebody has written a plugin that launches an application when you type the command for building?? That's insane.

Comment: i dont type, im using right click on Maven -> Maven install in eclipse. Not only this is launched, this was not the complete pom.xml

Comment: debug phase is activated after maven builds

Comment: Okay for me this falls under the category of people using Maven to do things it was never designed for. Hopefully somebody else can offer you some advice (*my* advice would be, wean yourself off over-reliance on Maven).

Comment: No idea? Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: On the other side, we are talking about the Problem and not the People. ;)